# Undefined 404 and React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency

Tags: reactjs, dependencies, react-hooks, http-status-code-404

I have a super cute site for flower-fans where you can find a profile of a flower (a mock api), read some info and put a note on each and every flower. Though, I'm not able to make the note stick anymore. So frustrating as it worked a while ago. I have updated the dependencies and also the settings for deploying on Netlify. In Postman I get the same message as in the console, which is not found 404.

I get a message in Terminal that the React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency (flowerId) too.

Down below you'll see the error message and here is a link to my deployed site:
https://flowerinspoapi.netlify.app/

Error message from Console

```
 GET https://flowerinspoapi.netlify.app/flowers/undefined 404
```

Code from Flowerinfo.js

```
// Fetching the comments for the flowers
const url = "https://flowers-mock-data.firebaseio.com/comments/TheresaUlwahn"

export const FlowerInfo = () => {
  const { flowerId } = useParams()
  const [flower, setFlower] = useState([])
  const [flowerMessages, setFlowerMessages] = useState([])
  const [postedMessage, setPostedMessage] = useState("")

  // Fetching the ID of the flowers 
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://flowers-mock-data.firebaseio.com/flowers/${flowerId}.json`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => {
        setFlower(json)
      })
  }, [flowerId])

  // Fetching the messages
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://flowers-mock-data.firebaseio.com/comments/TheresaUlwahn/${flowerId}.json`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => {
        console.log('All messages for the flower: ', json)
        if (json !== null) {
          setFlowerMessages(json)
        }
      })
  }, [postedMessage])

  const handleFormSubmit = (flowerId, message) => {
    // console.log('POST THIS MESSAGE: ', message, 'FOR THE FLOWER: ', flowerId);

    fetch(url + `/${flowerId}/.json`, {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({ message }),
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
    })
      .then(() => {
        console.log('posted  !')
        // window.location.reload();
        setPostedMessage(message)
      })
      .catch(err => console.log("error:", err))
  }

  var result = Object.keys(flowerMessages).map(function (key) {
    return [key, flowerMessages[key]];
  });
```